# How to declare select entity data type in Entity Framework?

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, orm, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

```
    Dim itemList    

    itemList = From items In Context.Product
               Select New With {Key .Code = items.ITEM_CODE_, Key .Name = items.ITEM_NAME, Key .Eancode = items.EANCODE}    

    Dim sortList = itemList.Where(Function(u) u.Name.Contains("soap"))
```

When I execute last line, I am getting an error:

> "Method invocation failed because 'Public Function Where(predicate As
>   String, ParamArray parameters As
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter()) As
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[[VB$AnonymousType_2(Of
>   VB$AnonymousType_2(Of Integer,String,String))' cannot be called with
>   these arguments:" & vbCrLf & "    Argument matching parameter
>   'predicate' cannot convert from 'VB$AnonymousDelegate_0(Of
>   Object,Object)' to 'String'."

Actually I want to pass an `itemList` entity to another method and in that method I want to use filter/sorting option dynamically.

Like below

```
    Dim itemList

    itemList = From items In Context.Product
               Select New With {Key .Code = items.ITEM_CODE_, Key .Name = items.ITEM_NAME, Key .Eancode = items.EANCODE}        
    Call LoadData(itemList)

Sub LoadData(itemList as Object)
    Dim sortList = itemList.Where(Function(u) u.Name.Contains("soap"))
End Sub
```

Please share me your suggestions how it can be solved?

Answer (score 2):

Just create a new class with properties `Code`, `Name` and `Eancode`.

```
Public Class ProductRow
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Code As String   
    Public Property Eancode As String     
End Class
```

And instead of using an anonymous type, use this type:

```
Dim itemList
itemList = From items In Context.Product
           Select New ProductRow With {Key .Code = items.ITEM_CODE_, Key .Name = items.ITEM_NAME, Key .Eancode = items.EANCODE}        
Call LoadData(itemList)
```

Then you are able to pass it to another function:

```
Sub LoadData(itemList as IQueryable(Of ProductRow))
    Dim sortList = itemList.Where(Function(u) u.Name.Contains("soap"))
End Sub
```

**Edit:**
If you know the column name only at runtime, then you need something like the [dynamic LINQ library](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_linq/article.php/c16829/Using-LINQ-with-Dynamic-Where-Clauses.htm). In this case, you can work with `IQueryable(Of Product)`:

```
Sub LoadData(itemList as IQueryable(Of Product))
    Dim sortList = itemList.Where("ColumnXY LIKE '%soap%'");
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Marc. But i want to filter by dynamic column like below [Dim sortList = itemList.Where(Function(u) u.Name.Contains("soap"))
Dim sortList = itemList.Where(Function(u) u.Code.Contains(10))] Is this possible with dynamic filter?

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamic filter". Do you have an example? Because u.Name.Contains("soap") or u.Code.Contains(10) is already possible..

Comment: Suppose I will filter by Name like Dim sortList = itemList.Where(Function(u) u.Name.Contains("soap")). Later user wants to filter data by Code so how can i replace Code in that above expression instead of Name.